# CSV to XML add more header

Tags: php, xml, csv

I've got the following problem:

I have a csv file, that I can convert to XML via a php script.

This way, every field goes under the same row in the xml, and I want the `product_sku` field go under a different row, for example call it `SKU_row`.

The CSV looks like this:

[my CSV file](http://hangszerkozpont.hu/rendel/1/faszom.csv)

The XML looks like this:

[my XML file](http://hangszerkozpont.hu/rendel/1/faszom.xml)

PHP file code that I run to convert the CSV to XML:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

function PrepareXMLName($PrepareString)
{

    $PrepareString = str_replace(" ","",$PrepareString);
    $PrepareString = preg_replace('#\W#', '', $PrepareString);
    $PrepareString = str_replace("ZSPAZESZ","",$PrepareString);
    $PrepareString = strtolower($PrepareString);

    return $PrepareString;
}   

$inputFilename    = 'faszom.csv';
$outputFilename   = 'faszom.xml';

// Open csv to read
$inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
$doc  = new DomDocument();
$doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
$root = $doc->createElement('rows');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
{
    $container = $doc->createElement('row');
    foreach ($headers as $i => $header)
        {
        $header = str_replace(chr(32),"_",trim($header));
        $header = strtolower($header);
        if($header==''){ $header = 'empty';}
        $header = PrepareXMLName($header);
        if(is_numeric($header)) { $header = "number-". $header; }
        //echo "HERE: " . $header . "<br />";  
        $child = $doc->createElement($header);
        $child = $container->appendChild($child);
        $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
        $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }
    $root->appendChild($container);
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");
$strxml = $doc->saveXML();
$handle = fopen($outputFilename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $strxml);
fclose($handle);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

How can I do in this PHP file, to let it put the `product_sku` fields under a different row, to be it separated from the row in which customer data's are?

Answer (score 0):

XML allows you to group on a further level. So instead of your flat row model:

```
<rows>
    <row>
        <product_sku>L162L</product_sku>
        <order_entity_id>31</order_entity_id>
        <order_customer_firstname>Teszt</order_customer_firstname>
        <product_qty_ordered>1.0000</product_qty_ordered>
    </row>
```

You can group further on depending on the context of the data, for example by order, product and customer:

```
<rows>
    <row>
        <product>
            <sku>L162L</sku>
            <qty_ordered>1.0000</qty_ordered>
        <product>
        <order>
            <entity_id>31</entity_id>
            <customer>
                <firstname>Teszt</firstname>
            </customer>                
        </order>            
    </row>
```

But this depends *entirely* of what you want and from your question I don't see any reason on why to do it this, that or any other way nor what stands in your way to do whatever you want.

Comment: That what you posted below, that's exactly what I want to do, but with that php file. And I'm looking for the solution, how to group the XML elements via that php file. Thanks.

Comment: Every node in a DOMDocument has a parent (but not the document node). So you can also add children :) so you create an element and then you add it as a child. That's technically exactly what you've done already. Just take the parent you want. You should also be able to find existing Q&A material on how this can be done with the DOM in PHP. Do not ask for code, search for it.

Comment: I totally stuck with this :( I'm not a programmer, could you please help me a bit how to do it? Just a sample modified code, and the rest maybe I can do myself. Thank!